# Eigenvector of parameterized Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, parametric

Given the matrix for $a, b \in (0,1)$

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1-a & a \\
    b & 1-b \end{pmatrix}$$

The eigenvalues are $\lambda_1 = 1$ and $\lambda_2 = -a -b +1$.

We want to find the eigenvectors based on that so we solve

$$ (\begin{pmatrix} 1-a & a \\
    b & 1-b \end{pmatrix} - I) x = \begin{pmatrix} -a & a \\
    b & -b \end{pmatrix}x  = 0$$

which gives $-a x_1 + a x_2 = 0 \Rightarrow x_1 = x_2$, and $bx_1 - bx_2 = 0$ which doesn't get me anywhere ...

Same for the other eigenvalue

$$  \begin{pmatrix} b & a \\
    b & a \end{pmatrix}x  = 0$$

This matrix is even linear dependent. What am I missing?

Comment: "Which doesn't get me anywhere". This incorrect. It does get you somewhere. You get that the eigenvectors associated to $1$ are the non-null multiples of $\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$. In fact, since the sum of the rows is constant, it is well known that the $\bf 1$ vector is an eigenvector associated to that same constant.

Comment: Some of your calculation is incorrect too. :)

Comment: Which part is incorrect?

Comment: A nice tip: in general, if a square matrix has a nontrivial kernel, then the system of equations for membership in its kernel contains at least one redundant equation. This means that in the $2 \times 2$ case, you can choose any nonzero row and ignore the other row in order to identify the kernel (and therefore to identify an eigenspace). So for example, in the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 5 \end{bmatrix}$, there is an eigenvalue of $1$, and you can identify the associated eigenspace by only considering the equation $x_1+2x_2=0$ and ignoring the equation $2x_1+4x_2=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) For $\lambda=1$, you have $x_1=x_2$, so the eigenvalues are the nonzero multiples of $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$

2) For $\lambda=1-a-b$, you have $bx_1+ax_2=0$, so $bx_1=-ax_2$ and

the eigenvalues are the nonzero multiples of $\begin{bmatrix}a\\-b\end{bmatrix}$